# NodeJS POST Request Over JSON-RPC

Tags: json, node.js, rest, json-rpc, ethereum

I am trying to execute a POST request over JSON-RPC on my NodeJS server. Converting the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["pass"],"id":74}' http://localhost:8545
```

In NodeJS I keep receiving:

```
200 {"id":-1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Could not decode request"}}
```

In the header I am specifying the Content-Type. If someone can point out what I am not specifying and how to add it in it would be much appreciated.

```
var headers = {
    'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-Type':     'application/json-rpc',
    'Accept':'application/json-rpc'
}

var options = {
    url: "http://localhost:8545",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    form: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["pass"],"id":1}
}

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.write(res.statusCode.toString() + " " + body);
    }else{
      res.writeHeader(response.statusCode, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      res.write(response.statusCode.toString() + " " + error);
    }
    res.end();
})
```

Answer (score 3):

`form` is for `application/x-www-url-encoded` requests, not JSON. Try these options instead:

```
var options = {
  url: "http://localhost:8545",
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body: JSON.stringify({
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    method: 'personal_newAccount',
    params: ['pass'],
    id: 1
  })
}
```

You can also set `json: true` in your options to have `request` automatically parse the response as JSON.

Comment: I can't seam to get it to work can you look at the curl request I'm trying to copy above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `--header` option:

```
curl --request POST \
    --header 'Content-type: application/json' \
    --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["pass"],"id":74}' \
    http://localhost:8545
```

Answer (score 0):

To use "personal_newAccount" and the rest options from [Ethereum Docs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#list-of-management-apis) you need to start the server with the needed API's:

```
--rpcapi "personal,eth,web3"
```